# Nginx serving php as text (want to serve html, not php)

Tags: nginx

Here is my basic config:

```
server {
  server_name mysite.dev;
  root location/of/my/html;

  location / {
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```

Yet when I browse to `mysite.dev` I receive text for a php file:

```
<?php  

if(!defined('APPLICATION_ENV')) {
  define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));
}

define('ROOT_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
define('LIBRARY_PATH', ROOT_PATH . '/library');

.....etc
```

Here's the thing, I don't even want to serve PHP at all. I just want to serve the files as they are, no server-side processing.

Comment: "I don't even want to serve PHP at all. I just want to serve the files as they are, no server-side processing." That's what's happening.

Comment: @ceejayoz not exactly, there isn't even a php file in that directory, so where it is coming from? I only have a html file in the root directory.

Answer (score 1):

One of two things is happening.

1. **You did receive the file as it was.** The file you requested was a php file. However, because nginx isn't configured to run it through a php interpreter it simply delivered the file to your browser. If you don't want to see the php code in that file, either remove the code from the file or ask for a file without php code in it.
2. **Your client isn't talking to the right server.** Make sure the client is resolving to the correct machine and that `nginx` is handling the request. `netstat -lpt | grep http`

Comment: The php file isn't present in the `root/to/html` directory. I only have an `index.html` file in there, so how is it serving a php file, and from where? I don't have php configured. Just trying to serve a static html file.

Comment: @Zenph `cat` the index.html file. You should see the php tags.

Comment: I'm afraid not. The html file contains nothing but html, starts with `<!DOCTYPE html>`, I know because I coded it. I haven't used php once. Completely lost why it is serving a php file as text that doesn't even exist in the root.

Comment: That server is not used anywhere else. I can replicate by doing `server_name someotherserver.com`, and it defaults to serving static php text file.

Comment: One way to make sure you are using the right config is to telnet to the IP and port and type: `GET / HTTP/1.1` followed by `Host: mysite.dev`and two newlines. Then the access log is your friend especially if you log the server_name that nginx believe it is supposed to serve.